# I put five times (1.25 cup vs 0.25 cup) the recipe's amount of water but the correct amount of oil into my brownie mix

Tags: water, brownies

I put 1 & 1/4 cup of water & 1/3 cup of oil in my brownie mix. The recipe calls for 1/4 cup of water & 1/3 cup of oil. I added a second box of brownie mix. Should I add another 1/3 c of oil since there is already too much water? It will also require 2 eggs. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

As you added five times as much water as it needed, you really need to multiply *everything* else by 5 too.

I'm not really sure I see an easy way out of this.
You could try pouring onto a shallow tray & see if it will dry sufficiently if you bake it maybe twice as long at half the temperature, but really you're in unchartered territory.